# UIButton inside table not triggering

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Hello I'm trying to figure out how to call a UIButton inside a custom cell within a UItable in storyboard. At the moment I have a library that creates a sidemenu working just fine (more info here) and I can see the button I placed when I launch the simulator. However, when I click on the button the action is **not** triggered, can you please guide me as to how I can achieve this?

**Important to note** that the table was create entirely in storyboard.

My work in progress code within `TopratedVC.swift` to get the button to trigger the action:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewVibrantCell") as! CellClassMenu

    cell.sendFeedBackBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.sendFeedBackBtn.addTarget(self, action: "sendFeedBackBtnAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = false //tried with true as well, no difference
    cell.bringSubviewToFront(cell.sendFeedBackBtn)
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return cell
}

func sendFeedBackBtnAction(sender: UIButton){

    print("sendFeedBackBtnAction tapped")
}
```

My `UITableViewVibrantCell.swift` file contains the following:

```
import UIKit

class UITableViewVibrantCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var sendFeedBackBtn: UIButton!
}
```

My `sndFeedBackBtn` has a referencing outlet to  `UITableViewVibrantCellsendFeedBackBtn` which has a class of `UITableViewVibrantCell`.  What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

What it looks like in simulator:
[image]

Comment: Why dont you just make a @IBAction of that button in your UITableViewCell class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post, you show a `UITableViewVibrantCell` class, and dequeue a cell with the "UITableViewVibrantCell" identifier, but cast it as `CellClassMenu`?

Anyhow, it would be better practice to create a cell delegate for actions, and let your controller decide the implementation, rather than adding a target every time the cell is dequeued. You can do that like so:

#### UITableViewVibrantCell

```
import UIKit

protocol UITableViewVibrantCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton)
}

class UITableViewVibrantCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: UITableViewVibrantCellDelegate?
    @IBOutlet var feedbackButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        feedBackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }
    func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.buttonPressed(sender)
    }
}
```

#### TopratedVC

```
class TopratedVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewVibrantCell") as! UITableViewVibrantCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewVibrantCellDelegate
    func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("feedbackButton tapped")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selectors ("sendFeedBackBtnAction:") can't pass parameters. And a param isn't needed in the sendFeedBackBtnAction function since you're calling it only for this button. So change I'd change it to simply...

```
func sendFeedBackBtnAction()
```

then I'd also recommend changing your selector to a more updated swift version...

```
cell.sendFeedBackBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendFeedBackBtnAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```